# Linux: Possible to detect if USB device is connected and charging, but switched off

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

In Linux, is it possible to detect whether a USB device (such as a cellphone) is physically connected, even if the device is switched off (USB microcontroller on the peripheral not powered)?

Comment: Only if the device communicates that information, and lets you read it when the device is powered off. Is there specific case you're interested in by chance, or are you looking more for a lib/driver that gives this information back?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to try with lsusb, with max verbose output, i.e:

> $ sudo lsusb -vv

Alternatively, if you already are root:

> # lsusb -vv